# NSURLConnection closed during HTTP Server Push

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

I am connecting to an HTTP url using NSURLConnection. I am supposed to get response (more then one data package) after some time intervals, but NSURLConnection ,immediately, become closed. Is there is any way to prevent this? Or the CFNetwork would be only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NSURLConnection within an NSOperation, or some of other kind of managed background thread?

The nature of async operations can cause this to happen. More information would help diagnose this issue though.

Comment: No, I don't use NSOperation at all. Problem was with strange behavior of NSURLConnection. Think that we resolved this by using CFNetwork instead. 
But, thanks, anyway. :)